# When should you repeat levels instead of warping to final level

Tags: risk-of-rain

My goal is to beat the final boss so you can ignore reasoning that includes achievements/unlockables/highscores.

After reaching the 4th teleporter you can choose to warp to the final level or replay previous levels. When should you choose to replay levels and not warp right to final level?

There are plenty of chests and you can farm experience in the last level before the boss. If your goal is to defeat the final boss, is there ever a reason to repeat levels?

Comment: If you want to go for the final boss, then I'd say do it straight away. But some achievements are much simpler by just doing reruns, and it also helps with farming monster logs. So it depends on what you want to do. I usually decide upfront whether I want to beat the Providence or do several reruns for some other goal. That being said, if you do 2 or 3 full reruns you can get essentially invincible which will also help with the Providence, of course. But that takes a while...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Risk of Rain has a progressive leveling system for enemies, I can see no reason to replay levels unless you have a specific item you want to get (like the [Ceremonial Dagger](http://risk-of-rain.wikia.com/wiki/Items)).  Otherwise, you are just fighting harder enemies and building up the final boss.  I feel it is better to just attempt the final boss when you reach the 4th teleporter.

Comment: Are enemies still leveling after reaching "HAHAHAHAHA" difficulty? If not so - it may be reasonable to farm your level on previous stages.

Comment: @WojciechŻółtak At the very least they get more numerous. I did a 3 hour run the other day and on the fourth rerun of the first level, I had 5 Magma Worms on the screen, three of which were Overloading Magma Worms. That didn't happen when I first hit HAHAHAHA.

Comment: According to following source difficulty **does** continue to increase at the same rate even once the bar is maxed on "HAHAHAHA"

http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty